# HTML - box shadow isnt working with rounded square even with transparancy

Tags: html, css

im trying to add a image that acts as a button and the image is a rounded square where the 4 corners are transparent. I add it to my webpage like this :

```
<input type="image"id = "LeftButton" src="graphics/leftarrow.png" >
```

and style it like this:

```
#LeftButton{
    background-color: Transparent;
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:32.5px;
    width: 45px;
    box-shadow: 10px -10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    height: 45px;
}
```

I have coloured the background of the div its in red so you can see better in the image [image: HERE]

thanks

Comment: try to add `border-radius: 4px;`

Comment: you just set the border-radius to your input and check it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [`box shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) uses information from the box shape to generate the shadow in order to display as intended you will need to add a [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) to your input

```css
#LeftButton{
    background-color: Transparent;
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:32.5px;
    width: 45px;
    box-shadow: 10px -10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<input type="image"id = "LeftButton" src="graphics/leftarrow.png" >
and style it like this:
```

Comment: If you found the answer useful please consider up voting